# Analytics Management API - insufficient permissions when patching adwords link

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

What I am trying to do is to insert new profile id to Webproperty Adwords Link.

There are already some profiles added to this link - lets call them xxxxxx and yyyyyy.

To add a new one I use this method: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webPropertyAdWordsLinks/patch#request

- I create a new profile via API and i have its id - let's say its: zzzzzz
- Next i use this method: PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/accountId/webproperties/webPropertyId/entityAdWordsLinks/webPropertyAdWordsLinkId
  with following body:

  { 'profileIds' => ['xxxxxx', 'yyyyyy', 'zzzzzz'] }

And i got an error: "User does not have sufficient permissions for this PROFILE with ID yyyyyy."
It seems like i dont have a permission to access this yyyyyy profile but its already there - i just want to add zzzzzz profile. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I would post your error message to the beta forum since you have access someone there should be able to help.

Comment: Your question seems a bit confused. You say you are calling patch on a view (profile) but the API request you posted was the adwords links API request.